# using Find/Grep to search files between specific time of day

Tags: linux, unix, find, grep, cygwin

I can use the following command to search log files over the past 10 days:

```
find . -type f -mtime -10 |xargs grep -i -n 'exception' 2> /dev/null
```

But i want to further limit the search for lines in the file that are logged between *6am* and *6pm*. I'm wondering how i can modify the grep command to filter these if the lines look like this:

```
2012-09-04 03:50:41,658 [MainLogger: ] EXCEPTION  AppLog - some exception 1
2012-09-04 10:01:32,902 [MainLogger: ] EXCEPTION  AppLog - some exception 2
2012-09-04 15:39:51,901 [MainLogger: ] EXCEPTION  AppLog - some exception 3
2012-09-04 18:12:51,901 [MainLogger: ] EXCEPTION  AppLog - some exception 4
```

In the above case on lines 2 and 3 should be returned since they are between *6am* and *6pm*.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy **ugly** way to do it could be adding a lot of greps, like this :

```
find . -type f -mtime -10 |xargs grep -i -n 'exception' | grep -v " 00" | grep -v " 01" | ... | grep -v " 18" | grep -v " 19" ... 2> /dev/null
```

Or more concisely :

```
find . -type f -mtime -10 |xargs grep -i -n 'exception' | grep -v -e " \(0[012345]\|18\|19\|2[0123]\)" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it like this:

```
grep ' 0[6789]:\| 1[01234567]\| 18:00:00,000'
```

But if you will need some more time handling, I recommend switching to a more powerful language (e.g. Perl and [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime)).

Answer (score 0):

In any language with a proper datetime library, converting all dates to a canonical representation makes the problem trivial. The default canonicalization is to convert to seconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970. Then just see if the canonical number of the input line is bigger than the start time and smaller than the end time.